# What are equivalent GCC flags for Visual Studio Warning Levels?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-warnings

I've got that application that gets built by GCC and by the Visual Studio Compiler using Makefiles.

The code shall compile warning-free under Warning Level 4 of Visual Studio (VS is the leading compiler) and some projects need Warning Level 3 set.

What are the corresponding `-Wsomething` flags that need to be passed to GCC so that the warning levels are equal?

I need the settings for `/W4` and `/W3`, for completeness, `/W2` and `/W1` would be appreciated.

For `/W4`, I currently use these flags:

```
-Wall
-Wno-comment
-Wno-parentheses
-Wno-missing-braces
-Wno-char-subscripts
-Wno-write-strings
-Wno-unknown-pragmas
```

Comment: From a cmd prompt, cd to VC++ bin directory, run vcvars32 then type cl /?.  It will tell you all the compiler flags for visual C++.  There are about 5 pages worth of compiler flags.

Comment: @cup: I don't need the flags for VS, I need them for GCC. I Know that there's `W4`..`W0` but I need to know what I have to pass to GCC.

Comment: There won't be any perfect equivalent, VS emits some nonsensical warnings that would never be accepted in gcc. Start from `-Wall -Wextra` and remove those you don't like with `-Wno-*` like you are already doing. With clang you could try `-Weverything`.

Comment: @eckes, some time have passed since you asked that question.. I have exactly the same question and the same problematic. Are there any updates / experiences you could share? Which warnings did you use for your project, or which guideline have you followed?

Comment: @yussuf I switched for another approach and decided to tighten things up a bit: I'm no longer aiming for the **same** settings but instead use stricter settings with GCC. On GCC, I compile with `-Wall -Wextra` (yes, both since `-Wall` isn't implicitly enabled when `-Wextra` is present) and stick to `/W4` for Windows. When I asked the question, we had no CI running; in the meanwhile every build is run on Linux and Windows, so we spot issues immediately.

Comment: Thanks for coming back on that. Actually, having exactly the same settings isn't required for our projects as well; we just want to ensure every project uses comparable and minimum warning levels; while VC's W4 is the guideline... So all platforms building with GCC should use same settings. How can you tell that `-Wall` and `-Wextra`is more strict than W4 on VC? It would help me to have some paper that I can use for reference...

Comment: @yussuf IMHO such a paper isn't available, maybe you can produce one ;-) The GCC warnings for `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are nicely described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html. However, I'm not aware of such an overview for MSVC. My **subjective** impression is that `-Wall -Wextra` is stricter than `/W4` but this can be caused by the fact that I'm mainly on Windows and therefore only GCC warnings are reported after pushing with 0 MSVC warnings...

Comment: OK, seems I have to do some research ;) thanks alot!

Comment: @yussuf: if you're done don't forget to publish your results here ;-)